# Kotlin : How to call API using Volly and get the Response synchronously via Callback method

Tags: android, kotlin

I am very new to Kotlin and Android Development. I am trying to call one external API (GET) and get the response so that i can parse the response and use the information as i want.

**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
   
   private fun drawResult()
   {  
       val response = getPrice("laptop",...) //How to call this method and get response
   }

   fun getPrice(label : String, callback: VolleyCallback, function: () -> Unit) {
      val url: String = "API_ENDPOINT"
      val strReq = StringRequest(
        Request.Method.GET, url,
        { response -> callback.onSuccess(response) }
    ) { volleyError -> callback.onError(volleyError.toString() + "") }
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(strReq)
}

}

interface VolleyCallback {
    fun onSuccess(result: String?)
    fun onError(result: String?)
}
```

I have created one method **getPrice**. I am trying to call this method in **drawResult()** and get the Response. But i am not able to understand how to do it in Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use-case `suspendCoroutine` would be a good choice.  https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html

With this you can convert your callback based methods to a suspending functions.

Inside the callback you can call `cont.resume(response)` for suspending function to resume with response or some error.

Example:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    val url =
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gayanvoice/volley-kotlin/master/data/sample.txt"

    GlobalScope.launch {
        //usage
        val text = getText(url)
        val text1 = getText(url)

        Log.d("VolleyTest-", text + text1)
    }

}
 //declare with return type you'll pass in cont.resume
suspend fun getText(url: String): String? =
    suspendCoroutine { cont ->
        val callback1 = Response.Listener<String> { response -> cont.resume(response) }

        val callback2 = Response.ErrorListener { error -> cont.resume(error.toString()) }

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, callback1, callback2)
        queue!!.add(stringRequest)
    }


}
```